# Three.js add 2d Text on Face of THREE.CylinderGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

As i coudn't find any valueable information i gonna ask here.
I need to add text (clickable Button) to a face (side) of a THREE.CylinderGeometry. The Text on each side is different. For better understanding i have a sketch drawing here: [image: Three.js clickable pyramid]

If it might help, here's my current status: https://jsfiddle.net/2uzq6g7z/
Each side of the pyramid got its different color. It's possible to turn the pyramid with the mouse. But i couldn't get text on a side of the pyramid.

Do i have to add it in here:

```
geometry.faces[i]...
```

Help appreciated :-)